# Three.js shadow casting trouble

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to create cartoonish weather visualisation in threejs, so I decided to first set up a basic scene with everything in place for a beautiful day, but I'm having trouble casting shadows. I copied the code for the lights from here on stackoverflow and the example works, but when I use it in my project it fails.

Here's the example:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/12939276/ImportedScene/index.html

I want a light which is inside the box and cast shadows as if it was the sun. I used a point light because I've read somewhere that you have to use orthographic camera for directional lights to cast shadows?

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, only DirectionalLight and SpotLight are able to cast shadow.

Then you have to activate shadow :

```
renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
directionalLight.castShadow = true;
object3D.castShadow = true;
anOtherObject3D.receiveShadow = true;
```

Comment: Excellent snippet solution!

Answer (score 2):

You have some console errors that need to be addressed, but your `spotlight` is basically working.

First, add a camera controller so you can spin the view and see what is happening:

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
```

Then update the controls in the animate function:

```
controls.update();
```

Add some axes so you can get a frame of reference:

```
scene.add(new THREE.AxisHelper() );
```

You will see that your spotlight is too close. Instead, set:

```
light.position.set( 5, 5, -5 );
```

Also, the shadow frustum can be reduced in size if you want.